# Why does this pin not fire the first time the command 43 comes in?

Tags: c++, timer, arduino, logic

I'm working on a timer for the end of a game in Arduino. Basically, the program gets a command from serial, flips a pin, waits for 5 seconds, then triggers a reset command. It works, but it doesn't do it the very first time '43' comes through the serial. It will do it the second time and work fine after that. Why is that? What am I missing?

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
elapsedMillis timeElapsed; 
int pin = 13;
unsigned int wait = 5000;

//// SERIAL //////////////////////////////////////////////
byte incomingByte; // from python
int command = 0; // command (1 = open, 2 = close)
int servoCom = 0; // the incoming command shit

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  Serial.println("setup done");

  // wait 20 ms
  delay(20);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    incomingByte = Serial.read(); 
    command = incomingByte;
    servoCom = ServoGo(command);  
  }

  if (servoCom == 43){
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    // run for 5 seconds
    if (timeElapsed >= wait) 
    { 
      // trigger reset
      servoCom = 70;  
    }
  }
  if(servoCom == 70){
    // reset 
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    timeElapsed = 0; 
  } 
}

int ServoGo(int com)
{
    Serial.println("!inServoGo");
    Serial.println(com);
    return com;
}
```

Comment: Because you do not assign an initial value to `timeElapsed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeElapsed` is not initialized to zero at setup; it got reinitialized after the first command 70, then only command 23 works properly.

Comment: Yep that was it. Totally missed that.  Additional question: When I do initialize it, the first time fires at 2 or 3 seconds instead of the full 5. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mishap_n Ask another question for this. It could be something unrelated. Plus we'd need to see your modified code. But just guessing, if you initialized the variable before you open your serial device, the time the serial initializes could be impacting your (clumsy) time calculation mechanism.